# How to see what line of code is currently being Ran Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

is there a way to see the currently line of code being ran in Xcode. With out using breakpoints but. A simple list of executions during run time. That were done on which line of code. So I can see where I'm at.

Comment: Why "without using breakpoints"?

Comment: because if have a lot of code that's goes a lot of different places in my app all starting from one function so i would have to set like 100 breakpoints to all the sub-functions just to see where its getting stuck. But figured if i can this see where Xcode is at then wait till it gets stuck and then look at the piece of code that Xcode is currently is at then i know what function its at @Connor

Comment: Got it. You can still do what you want via breakpoints, without setting 100 of them. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use breakpoints. The OP mentioned he didn't want to have to set a ton of breakpoints to check every line, but that is not necessary.[image: Breakpoints]

This toolbar appears when execution is stopped via breakpoint. You can tap the fourth icon (with the bent arrow) to "step through" the application - this will advance execution 1 line at a time. Try out the last two buttons (step into and step out) while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a few places where you think the code is executed, you can use `NSLog()` statements and see what is being printed to the console at what time.

or

Set a breakpoint (tap on a line number in Xcode) and manually run the code line by line using Xcode's `Debug` menu. In your case you can set a breakpoint on the method that is executed when a button is pushed. If you do not know which method is called when you push the button, you could look at where the button is declared, which should have a `addTarget` method, or see what it is hooked up to in the Storyboard.